# Inheriting from a class with a private inner classes C++

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, tree, avl-tree

So I have an assignment in which I need to use a rank binary tree. I've already implemented a template AVL tree (C++) a while back so I thought of using it as a basis and adding to it. 
Since I don't want to duplicate code and work with what I have, I thought of making a rank tree class that'll inherit from the AVL.
How can I use what I have to create a template rank AVL tree?
Is there a way to create an inner RankNode class and have it inherit from AVL's private Node class?

```
/* AvlTree class */
template<typename KeyType, typename DataType>
class AvlTree {
    class AvlTreeNode;
    AvlTreeNode* root;
    int treeSize;

    void clearTree(AvlTreeNode* node);
    void updateBF(AvlTreeNode*& node); //updates the BF of the nodes from the root to the given node
    void updateHeight(AvlTreeNode*& node); //updates the height of the nodes from the root to the given node
    void balanceTree(AvlTreeNode*& node);
    void rotateLeft(AvlTreeNode*& node);
    void rotateRight(AvlTreeNode*& node);
    void insertFrom(const KeyType& key, const DataType& data, AvlTreeNode*& node);
    AvlTreeNode*& findNext(AvlTreeNode*& node, AvlTreeNode*& current,AvlTreeNode*& father);
    AvlTreeNode*& treeNav(AvlTreeNode*& node);
    void deleteLeaf(AvlTreeNode*& node);
    void deleteOneSon(AvlTreeNode*& node);
    void deleteTwoSons(AvlTreeNode*& node);
    void removeFromTree(const KeyType& key, AvlTreeNode*& node);
    AvlTreeNode* find(KeyType key, AvlTreeNode*& node);
    void inOrderAux(KeyType** keys, AvlTreeNode*& node, int& i);
    void inOrderRangedAux(KeyType** keys, AvlTreeNode*& node, const KeyType& start,const KeyType& end, int& i);
    void inOrderRangedCountAux(AvlTreeNode*& node, const KeyType& start,const KeyType& end, int& i);

public:
    AvlTree();
    virtual ~AvlTree();
    //AvlTree(const AvlTree& tree);
    DataType getData(const KeyType& key);
    void setData(const KeyType& key, const DataType& data);
    void insert(const KeyType& key, const DataType& data);
    void remove(const KeyType& key);
    void inOrder(int* size, KeyType** keys); //Gets all of the values in a Keyarray inorder
    void inOrderRanged(int* size, KeyType** keys,const KeyType& start,const KeyType& end);
    bool exists(const KeyType& key);
} ;

/* AvlTreeNode class */
template<typename KeyType, typename DataType>
class AvlTree<KeyType,DataType>::AvlTreeNode {
    KeyType key;
    DataType data;
    int bf;  
    int height; //The subtree's height
    AvlTreeNode* left;
    AvlTreeNode* right;
    AvlTreeNode(KeyType key, DataType data, AvlTreeNode* left = NULL, AvlTreeNode* right = NULL):key(key), data(data), bf(0),height(0), left(left), right(right){}
    ~AvlTreeNode(){}
    friend class AvlTree<KeyType, DataType>;
};
```

Edit: I've found the answer I was looking for. The code I needed looks like this:

```
template<typename T>
class A{
protected:
    class B{


    };
};

template<typename T>
class C : A{
protected:
    class D :A<T>::B{

    };
};
```

Answer (score 4):

You can either mark the new class as `friend` of base (bad idea, design-wise), or make those private members protected (that's what `protected` is for, after all).

As for why `friend` isn't the best idea here: for one, base class shouldn't care about derived classes. Secondly, if you want to extend something, that something should be initially (or retroactively) made extendible; that is, it should mark members that might be exposed to derived classes as `protected`. Otherwise, the class is locked in; as such, it sends simple signal: *My original creator didn't want me extended*.

Comment: Maybe mention _why_ `friend` is a bad idea here. Something like "The base class should not need knowledge of its descendants."

Comment: If I make the Node (private) class Protected, will that let me overload it and add a rank field and functions to it?
Edit: To clarify, it's not that I'd like the Node class exposed to the inheriting classes, it's that I'd like to be able to "add to it".

Comment: @Shookie, if you need to extend member type, then you need it exposed; that is the rule, so your statement is self-contradicting.

Comment: @Griwes: So is there a way for me to build on the AVL implementation I already have or do I have? 
I mean, a rank tree is just another binary tree with additional data in each node (as far as I know). If I implement a rank tree it'll be identical except for the node class which will have another field and a few more functions. I just thought it'd be good programming to   make it inherit from the AVL.

Comment: @Shookie, as you're using pointers all over the place, yes (polymorphism will just do its job, if it's really just matter of additional data in each node).

Comment: @Griwes: I'm not sure what your answer referred to (mentioning the pointers). Can you please elaborate on how to use the polymorphism here? I'm not sure I understand how to extend the functionality of the Node class without actually adding the fields and functions I need to it.

Comment: @Shookie, you seem to lack real knowledge of polymorphism. I am not going to write the implementation for you. Read about how polymorphic pointers work, how `virtual` functions work, and then return to this problem.